# Is JProfiler able to performance native memory profiling?

Tags: jprofiler

Besides Heap memory, can JProfiler perform native memory profiling?

My java application is causing linux cgroup limit exceeded issue on production and would like to run profiling during development or performance test cycle.

Answer (score 0):

No, JProfiler only includes memory profiling for the Java heap.